# Raster Caculator Qgis 2.6 v/s Gdal_calc.py by Terminal

Tags: qgis, gdal, batch, gdal-calc

I need calculated monthly mean of Snowcover data by MODIS product, and then modify this script gdal_calc.py in this section

```
# create alphabetic list for storing input layers
AlphaList=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M",
       "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e"]
```

and wrote this script:

`!/bin/bash
echo -n "./gdal_calc.py " > comandos_py.sh
array=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M  N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e)
cont=0
for file in MCD10A1_*.tif ; do
  echo "map: $file"
  letra=${array[$cont]}
  echo -n "-$letra ${file} " >> comandos_py.sh
  cont=$[cont+1]
done
echo -n "--outfile=MEAN_2013_06.tif --calc=\"(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z+a+b+c+d)/30\" --NoDataValue=-9999 --type=Float32" >> comandos_py.sh`

both running well..... but the output file is incorrect...

in another way! load all file on QGIS 2.6, open RASTER CALCULATOR insert 30 image SNOWCOVER DAILY sum and divided by 30 and the output file IS CORRECT....

can someone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Because this array (input raster) includes 31 values:

```
array=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M  N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e)
```

and this one (output raster) only includes 29; where raster "L" and raster "e" are missing:

```
(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z+a+b+c+d)/30
```

However, the script would be (you have to repeat the letters):

```
!/bin/bash
echo -n "gdal_calc.py " > comandos_py.sh
array=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A B C D)
cont=0
for file in MCD10A1_*.tif ; do
  echo "map: $file"
  letra=${array[$cont]}
  echo -n "-$letra ${file} " >> comandos_py.sh
  cont=$[cont+1]
done
echo -n "--outfile=MEAN_2013_06.tif --calc=\"(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z+A+B+C+D)/30\" --NoDataValue=-9999 --type=Float32" >> comandos_py.sh
```

I tested it with 30 raster and it works! The first pixel of MEAN_2013_6.tif is the mean of the 30 raster; as it was manually corroborated with the gnome calculator.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Running my script version:

```
zeito@debian:~/Desktop/raster$ ./script
map: MCD10A1_10.tif
map: MCD10A1_11.tif
map: MCD10A1_12.tif
map: MCD10A1_13.tif
map: MCD10A1_14.tif
map: MCD10A1_15.tif
map: MCD10A1_16.tif
map: MCD10A1_17.tif
map: MCD10A1_18.tif
map: MCD10A1_19.tif
map: MCD10A1_1.tif
map: MCD10A1_20.tif
map: MCD10A1_21.tif
map: MCD10A1_22.tif
map: MCD10A1_23.tif
map: MCD10A1_24.tif
map: MCD10A1_25.tif
map: MCD10A1_26.tif
map: MCD10A1_27.tif
map: MCD10A1_28.tif
map: MCD10A1_29.tif
map: MCD10A1_2.tif
map: MCD10A1_30.tif
map: MCD10A1_3.tif
map: MCD10A1_4.tif
map: MCD10A1_5.tif
map: MCD10A1_6.tif
map: MCD10A1_7.tif
map: MCD10A1_8.tif
map: MCD10A1_9.tif
```

No errors!

Changing running mode in **comandos_py** and running it.

```
chmod +x comandos_py.sh
./comandos_py.sh
0 .. 100 - Done
```

No errors again!

Comment: I dont understand how this works.  I just tried `gdal_calc.py -A a1.tif -A r2.tif --outfile=res.tif --calc="(A + A)/2"` and `res.tif` just has the same values as `r2.tif`.  How can we give two different rasters the same argument and expect gdal to know the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for you Answer, but  I think so the problem ..... look at this!!!

david@XXXX:/media/fuse/dat3/modis/mod10a1/raw/monthly/regular/stack/dayly/2013_06$ ./crea_comandos_py.sh 
map: MCD10A1_2013152.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013153.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013154.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013155.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013156.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013157.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013158.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013159.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013160.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013161.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013162.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013163.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013164.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013165.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013166.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013167.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013168.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013169.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013170.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013171.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013172.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013173.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013174.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013175.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013176.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013177.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013178.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013179.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013180.tif
map: MCD10A1_2013181.tif
david@XXXX:/media/fuse/dat3/modis/mod10a1/raw/monthly/regular/stack/dayly/2013_06$ sh comandos_py.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gdal_calc.py", line 296, in 
    main()
  File "./gdal_calc.py", line 275, in main
    eval('parser.add_option("-%s", dest="%s", help="input gdal raster file, note you can use any letter A-Z")' %(myAlpha, myAlpha))
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1020, in add_option
    self._check_conflict(option)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 995, in _check_conflict
    option)
optparse.OptionConflictError: option -A: conflicting option string(s): -A
david@XXXX:/media/fuse/dat3/modis/mod10a1/raw/monthly/regular/stack/dayly/2013_06$ cat comandos_py.sh 
./gdal_calc.py -A MCD10A1_2013152.tif -B MCD10A1_2013153.tif -C MCD10A1_2013154.tif -D MCD10A1_2013155.tif -E MCD10A1_2013156.tif -F MCD10A1_2013157.tif -G MCD10A1_2013158.tif -H MCD10A1_2013159.tif -I MCD10A1_2013160.tif -J MCD10A1_2013161.tif -K MCD10A1_2013162.tif -L MCD10A1_2013163.tif -M MCD10A1_2013164.tif -N MCD10A1_2013165.tif -O MCD10A1_2013166.tif -P MCD10A1_2013167.tif -Q MCD10A1_2013168.tif -R MCD10A1_2013169.tif -S MCD10A1_2013170.tif -T MCD10A1_2013171.tif -U MCD10A1_2013172.tif -V MCD10A1_2013173.tif -W MCD10A1_2013174.tif -X MCD10A1_2013175.tif -Y MCD10A1_2013176.tif -Z MCD10A1_2013177.tif -A MCD10A1_2013178.tif -B MCD10A1_2013179.tif -C MCD10A1_2013180.tif -D MCD10A1_2013181.tif --outfile=MEAN_2013_06.tif  --calc="(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z+A+B+C+D)/30" --NoDataValue=-9999 --type=Float32david@gazp8:/media/fuse/dat3/modis/mod10a1/raw/monthly/regular/stack/dayly/2013_06$ ..

It so strange!!! Raster Calculator running ok [image]
[image]

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please, edit your answer with formated code because is unclear. I edited my answer with my results (running my own version of your script ). I didn't get any errors or strange results.

Answer (score -1):

xunilk's answer didnt work for me, so I had to implement a very hacky solution and make edits to `gdal_calc.py` directly.  But the edits were simple.

Just make the variable `AlphaList` on line 57 to be:

```
AlphaList=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M",
           "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
           "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m",
           "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
```

And then the script will be able to take tiffs marked with lowercase and accept up to 52 variables.