# How to change band type?

Tags: gdal, band

I have [an hillshade tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/146689/19460) for which the current band `type=Byte`may be problematic.

**How to change the band type to `type=float` ?**

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float32 input.tif output.tif
```

Seems you can choose between several float types: "Byte"/"Int16"/"UInt16"/"UInt32"/"Int32"/"Float32"/"Float64"/"CInt16"/"CInt32"/"CFloat32"/"CFloat64"

Comment: The answer has been edited but was initially correct: the **float** supported types are Float32/Float64/CFloat32/CFloat64.

Answer (score 3):

With **gdal_calc.py** is, for example, **--type Float32** (my answer based in your link). The next command worked for me when I used to calculate at-satellite brightness temperature:

```
gdal_calc.py -A b6.rad.tif --calc "1260.56/log((607.76/A)+1)" --type Float32 --outfile bright_temp.tif
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Did you tested it ? `--type='Float32'` clearly fails for me.

Comment: Of course. The above example was in my system with Ubuntu. In Debian, you can see my answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147457/raster-caculator-qgis-2-6-v-s-gdal-calc-py-by-terminal/147492#147492

Comment: If you have problems with **gdal_cal.py** the script is here: http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py. I copied it in an older Ubuntu system in **/usr/bin** and it worked nicely (I know that you use Linux for a recently question).

Comment: I indeed run on ubuntu. I used srtm tif, gdal hillshade, then gdal_calc with `type=Float32`, it fails. When `--calc=<equation>` is more basic, it behave as expected.