# Changing band datatype to uint64 using rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, numpy, typeerror

I have a raster, `input.tif`. It has 4 layers, and `uint8` datatype, as shown in the metadata:

```py
import rasterio

with rasterio.open('input.tif') as src:
    print(src.meta)
```

Output:

```
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'uint8', 'nodata': None, 'width': 16540, 'height': 16170, 'count': 4, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(3006), 'transform': Affine(10.000046118500606, 0.0, 316265.1384,
       0.0, -10.000256301793423, 6271819.2409)}
```

I would like to take the first band, convert it to `uint64`, and write the result to `output.tif`. I do, using NumPy:

```py
with rasterio.open('input.tif') as src:

    band1 = src.read(1)
    resband = np.uint64(band1)

    m = src.meta
    m['count'] = 1
    m['dtype'] = 'uint64'
    
    with rasterio.open('output.tif','w',**m) as dst:
        dst.write(resband, 1)
```

However, I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [233], in <cell line: 1>()
      7 m['count'] = 1
      8 m['dtype'] = 'uint64'
---> 10 with rasterio.open('output.tif','w',**m) as dst:
     11     dst.write(resband, 1)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/env.py:437, in ensure_env_with_credentials.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwds)
    434     session = DummySession()
    436 with env_ctor(session=session):
--> 437     return f(*args, **kwds)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py:163, in open(fp, mode, driver, width, height, count, crs, transform, dtype, nodata, sharing, **kwargs)
    161     raise TypeError("invalid driver: {0!r}".format(driver))
    162 if dtype and not check_dtype(dtype):
--> 163     raise TypeError("invalid dtype: {0!r}".format(dtype))
    164 if nodata is not None:
    165     nodata = float(nodata)

TypeError: invalid dtype: 'uint64'
```

How can I fix this error?

---

This question: [How to change band type?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147485/how-to-change-band-type) is similar but does not use rasterio.

Comment: Try `uint32`. According to the source code there is no `uint64` https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/dtypes.py#L21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [rasterio source code for dtypes](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/dtypes.py#L21), valid `dtypes` does not include `uint64`. Instead use `uint32`